# Conver a dataframe to a list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, list

So I've been trying to convert a dataframe into a list, with the pandas package on python, with the format as such:

```
[('row1 element1', 'row1 element2', 'row1 element3'), ('row2 element1', 'row2 element2', 'row2 element3'), ('row3 element1', 'row3 element2', 'row3 element3')...]
```

The closest I've managed is using the following snippet:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

however this gives the following format:

```
['row1 element1', 'row1 element2', 'row1 element3'],
['row2 element1', 'row2 element2', 'row2 element3'],
['row3 element1', 'row3 element2', 'row3 element3']...
```

Is there any simply way to obtain the format needed? Perhaps an existing method or a simple iterative process could be suggested. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an array of records for a fast approach:

```
df.to_records(index=False).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want convert list of lists to list of tuples, so:

```
>>> a = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18, 19]]
>>> [tuple(x) for x in a]
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11), (12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17), (18, 19)]
```